# My ACL Role is now showing selected contact groups

Tags: drupal, permissions, acl

I tried digging through other questions before I posed my own. So, I'm asking for a solution here.

**What I want to do:**
I want to give a group of contacts ability to 1. Create and edit events based on templates 2. See Event participants 3. See a select group of contacts that have custom fields, custom profiles and some with custom activities.

**What I have done so far:**
I have created a Role in Drupal and given a select number of Civi access including CiviEvents. I turned off *See All Civi* Contacts.

Then I created an ACL Role, Permission and ACL access
The ACL access includes most view activities related to contacts in the select group I want them to see. I also want them to see custom profiles and custom fields.

**Problem**
When I log into the website as an end user (member of the group) I can see the CiviCRM Menu, Add and Event, etc. But I am not able to see any contacts even though my ACL Role indicates I should be able to see this set of contacts and it is turned off in Drupal permission.

I also tried turning on the **See All Contacts** in Drupal and it showed me far more than I should be seeing with this user role.

I checked the ACL Roles against the Drupal ones and I am still running into problems. Any advice?

*I am using Drupal 7 and the Civi 4.7.24.*

Answer (score 0):

Without jumping in and working through the whole scenario, have you considered adding all their Participants to a Smart Group and giving your users an ACL that accesses just that Group of contacts

Comment: Its not just the participants they needs to see, also other selected groups. I also tested this out using just the parent group, still nothing.